# Why it does enter the if-statement

Tags: reactjs

I have this code:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if(prevProps.currentIndustry !== this.props.currentIndustry) {
        this.getMainProductGroups();
    }
}
```

It says, only when the `currentIndustry` property changed, it should enter the `if` statement and go to the method `getMainProductGroups()`.
As you can see in my screenshot (debug from `chrome` browser), it always enters this `if` statement, even when the values are the same. Any explanation for this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Hmm, seems impossible. I would try to print them to console instead.

Comment: Good Idea. I will try

Comment: Or maybe some invisible character is there. Try to compare the length of both strings.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger is only showing what method would be called when the condition meets. But it doesn't mean to go inside the if condition. To verify it, you may log:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if(prevProps.currentIndustry !== this.props.currentIndustry) {
        console.log('not matched'); // only logged if condition meets
        this.getMainProductGroups();
    }
}
```